# Can someone explain why viewing a tagged commit in GitHub lists tags the way it does?

Tags: github

In GitHub, when viewing the latest commit on a specific tag, the commit displays something like the following:

[image: Commit tags]

In the image above, the commit was tagged with v.16.52.0, but v.17.7.0 is a more recent tag in the repo. I'm curious why that one is bolded, and not the tag the commit was actually tagged with.

Expanding the ellipsis between those tag values displays all tags between the two. I'm not sure exactly what this is conveying.

Specifically, why is the most recent tag bolded, and not the tag the commit is actually tagged with?

Comment: It's showing all tags that contain the commit in their histories.

Comment: I understand that part, @SLaks, but I'm curious why the most recent tag is bold and not the actual tag that the commit was tagged with. It's a bit confusing.